# is it possible to obfuscate encrypted file?

Tags: encryption, hide

I mean running the command I get:

```
file Database.kdbx`
```

> Keepass password database 2.x KDBX

or

```
file test.gpg
```

> PGP RSA encrypted session key - keyid: E3E2DF27 2A6A3689 RSA (Encrypt or Sign) 1024b

**It is possible not give any information like this? is there any tool out there to hide this or make it look like another filetype?**

I've thought It would be a good thing when synchronizing one's passwords (best way after "give in hand" I think)

Comment: Yes, it's called *steganography*. See https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/steganography-hide-secret-data-inside-image-audio-file-seconds-0180936/

Comment: This may be a duplicte, though I could not find an active question quite the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of solutions depending on your requirements.

The way files are typically identified are based on the file extension and/or a header in the file. Modify how both of these and you are most of the way there.  Ofcourse their is no such thing as a free lunch, so there will always be some hassle factor.

In addition to tools which enable steganography as posited by DrMoishePippik I can think of at least 2 other solutions - You could create an image file with it's own filesystem and put the encrypted files in that. (On that note, truecrypt/veracrypt offers plausible deniability and might further your goals - although that's not what you asked).

You could also look at a file format that is not obviously encrypted - like a word document or zip file.

I posit you could encrypt a file using plain aes (so no header) and that would work as well.